# How to store LXC container's files in another folder

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, virtualization, udev, lxc

Well the answer seems to be given on https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-hostsetup page under ***Using a separate filesystem for the container store*** title but it doesn't work for me.

I have created a symlink for lxc folder pointing another folder in another partition (like suggested in the article), like

```
sudo ln -s /some/other/folder /var/lib/lxc
```

After that when I try to create a container I get following errors:

```
destan@xxx:~$ sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n testing
[sudo] password for destan: 

lxc-create: No config file specified, using the default config /etc/lxc/default.conf
Checking cache download in /var/cache/lxc/raring/rootfs-amd64 ... 
Copy /var/cache/lxc/raring/rootfs-amd64 to /var/lib/lxc/para/rootfs ... 
Copying rootfs to /var/lib/lxc/para/rootfs ...
/usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 207: /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 208: /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 210: /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 217: /dev/null: Permission denied
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
/usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 242: /dev/null: Permission denied
lxc-create: failed to execute template 'ubuntu'
lxc-create: aborted
```

Anybody having an idea?

Comment: Hi, i just did exactly this (used default storage path and a symlink to diff location) not 30 min ago and it worked fine (Gnu/Debian, not Ubuntu). I suspect it is an issue with how /some/other/folder is mounted. Can you post the relevant /etc/fstab line? Have your run lxc-checkconfig?

Comment: different location just works fine, the problem arises when you try different location on a different partitiion. Did you try with different partition?

Comment: yes, the symlink is to /media/vm/lxc that is a logical volume on a different logical group. I just installed lxc on my workstation and symlink'd to a second drive. the container is building just fine. are you able to write to /some/other/folder?

Comment: It's been a  while, can't remember what exactly happened but I couldn't get symlink solution working. Instead I am using `lxc.rootfs` config value to create the container in a folder on another partition.